# Make a bridge on my mac

Tags: linux, macos, networking, bridge, wireless-access-point

I have a Mac with WiFi connected to a router, internet works just fine there. I also have a PC with Linux Mint, and no wireless network card, so I connected them with a cable one to the other. Have enabled internet sharing at the Mac. I have also run `sudo sysctl -w net.inet.ip.forwarding=1` and `sudo sysctl -w net.link.ether.inet.proxyall=1`

Now they have their own LAN - from the Linux machine I can connect to the default gateway (192.168.3.1) and I see a webpage I setup on the mac which only displays "It works". But when I try to connect from the Linux machine to somewhere else I don't get a respond. For example when I try to get to the router at 192.169.2.1 the Linux fails, and the Mac displays the routers login page. Notice, they are on different LANs, since the network-mask is 255.255.255.0 (for both).

I don't really care if at the end they'll be connected at the same LAN or not. I just want the Linux machine to have internet access.

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to set up, on the Linux machine, routes and DNSs? For the route:

```
 sudo route add default gw 192.168.3.1
```

and for the DNSs you will have to edit as sudo the /etc/resolv.conf file, and add:

```
 nameserver 8.8.4.4
 nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

or whichever DNS you care to choose.

Comment: I did the `route` command now, the nameservers seem to bee OK. But still the same. And I don't think that nameservers are the problem, since I cannot reach my router at 192.168.2.1.

Comment: @Martin The reason why I asked about DNS is that, if you are able to reach your gateway, now I would like to know whether you can reach any outside site, not an internal one. Can you?

Comment: Well the physical connection goes like this PC->Mac->home router. From the PC I can reach the Mac, but not the home router.

Comment: I thought you said you could reach 192.168.3.1, and I had thought that was your home router. Could you please post the routing tables and ifconfig for both host and guest?